# looping "enter student id:" statement

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int id = 0;
    int pin = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    printf("enter student id: ");
    scanf("%i",&id);

    while(id !=0)
    {
        id /= 10;
        count1++;
    }

    while(count1 != 7)
    {    
        printf("the student id should be in 7 or 8 digits\n");
        printf("enter student id: ");
        scanf("%i",&id);       
    }

    if(count1 = 7)
    {
        printf("enter student pin: ");
        scanf("%i",&pin);       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I retype my student id, which is 7 digits, I expect to go to the next statement, but it keeps repeating same question.

How do I fix this?

Comment: if(count1 = 7) not a valid statement correct it to if(count1 == 7)

Comment: And `count1` is not modified in the while loop, which keep going while `count1 != 7` : it is an infinite loop.

Comment: ... and the following (corrected) `if (count1 == 7)` isn't even necessary.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a number of problems.

1. `if(count1 = 7)` assigns the value 7 to the variable count1, to make a comparison use `if(count1 == 7)`.
2. Every time the user enters a id, you need to check its length, not just the first time.  You could use some sort of loop and conditional.  If that condition is met (ie. student id length of 7 or 8 digits), then break the loop and continue.
3. Every time the user enters a new number, you need to reset `count1`, otherwise you will just continue increasing it infinitely.

For example you could do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int id = 0;
    int pin = 0;
    int count1 = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("enter student id: ");
        scanf("%i",&id);

        while(id !=0) {
            id /= 10;
            count1++;
        }

        if (count1 != 7 && count1 != 8) {    
            printf("the student id should be in 7 or 8 digits\n");
            count1 = 0;      
        }
        else break;
    }

    printf("enter student pin: ");
    scanf("%i",&pin); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am very glad you didn't suggest yoda conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `if (count1 = 7)`, `7` is assigned to `count1` and the condition is evaluated as truth because in c any non zero condition is true.

To prevent this you might want to turn on compiler warnings, if they were on the compiler would tell you to add explicit parentheses to an assignment used as a truth value.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32701442/1983495) although it still skips `scanf()`'s return value which is potentially invoking undefined behavior does solve your problem, but I have got a suggestion for you.

If you want to check how many digits were scanned you can use the `"%n"` specifier, like this

```
int
main(void)
{
    int value;
    int count;
    value = 0; /* initialized in case no valid characters are scanned */
    count = 0; /* initialized in case no valid characters are scanned */
    if ((scanf("%d%n", &value, &count) == 1) && (count == 7))
        fprintf(stderr, "ok, value is `%d'\n", value);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong length: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

You just need to read [`scanf()`'s manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) *Very Carefully* to figure this out, and also to learn how to validate input based on `scanf()`'s return value.